# While job running, the job failed with this error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssms

Executing the query `EXECUTE dbo.spudl_build_t_di_rilimits` failed with the following error:

> The statement has been terminated.
> Possible failure reasons:
> Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly,
> parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
> correctly.

Comment: Have you select the correct database in JobStep? Is there any mandatory parameter that you missed?

Comment: May be adding the procedure body would help to answer better

Comment: After code change I started the job in QA, while running the job I got the job failure with this error